# VHDL, how does concatenate work?

Tags: vhdl

I have some code in VHDL. I don't understand how concatenation works.

```
A   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
B   : IN IN STD_LOGIC;
A <= "1111";
B <= '0';


A <= A(2 DOWNTO 0) & B;
```

Is A "0111" or "1110"?

Comment: You need a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your 'code' above isn't valid VHDL.

Comment: left-to-right order is maintained (noting you don't specify the value of S_HITS_SRC1 or it's declaration). IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.5 Adding operators, para 2.

Comment: Sorry, *updated

Comment: Left and right are very important to VHDL. `B` is on the right, so its value will end up on the right of the concatenated value. ie, `A` will be `"1110"` (NB: double quotes for literals for `std_logic_vector`)

Comment: Are these assignments in a process or concurrent assignments? Are the separated by wait statements?  What is the value of A at the time of the second assignment? Your code is still not a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the value of A cannot be determined from it. (And that being said operands are associated left to right in concatenation).

Comment: Given the code shown so far, the answer is "neither".

Since you can't assign to IN ports, the assignments to `A` are illegal.

Comment: @weider - the best way forward for you is probably to start with another small example from a tutorial, and compile that with a simulator. Then adapt the example to do what you want, and come back to us when you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the concatenation itself is concerned, you seem to be doing that right, but apart from the other errors (you're assigning to an input, as BrianDrummond noted, and you've not got compilable syntax), you'll have a problem because VHDL signal assignments outside of a process are concurrent (i.e. they are evaluated continuously and in parallel).

So if you do:

```
A <= "1111";
A <= A(2 DOWNTO 0) & B;
```

You'll be assigning every bit of A with two drivers - a '1', and the bit on the left of it except for the least significant bit which gets assigned 'B'. Imagine constructing this with actual copper wires. You are tying all bits of A together - AND tying them to the positive voltage source.
If B is '1' this should resolve to all '1', but if B is '0' you will effectively connect the positive and negative voltage terminals, like a short circuit. Your simulator will tell you the result is 'X' - unknown.